# Controlling routes loading order from Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So in Rails3 Engines come with their own models/controllers/views and of course routes. Now the question is: How do you ensure that Engine routes will be loaded before (or after) application routes and all other Engines that are present?

Here's an example of my Rails app routes:

```
match '*(path)', :to => 'foo_controller#bar_action'
```

And my Engine:

```
match '/news', :to => 'bar_controller#foo_action'
```

So by default Engines routes will be loaded after the application ones. This means that Engine routes are inaccessible due to that catch-all route in my app. How can force Engine routes to be loaded first (or last)?

Comment: Have you tried looking at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html ? I'm pretty sure you can do what you want using hooks & initializers

Comment: Is that not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310832/how-to-override-rails-app-routes-from-an-engine ?

Comment: BTW, I believe engines routes are always loaded after the app routes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you're trying to do is kinda difficult. As has been mentioned engine routes are loaded after the app routes and overriding this behaviour may be problematic. I can think of several things that you can try.

**Use An Initializer After Routing Paths Initializer**

There is an initializer in `engine.rb` inside the rails source, one way to accomplish what you're after is to try to hook into the functionality that it deals with. The initializer looks like this by default:

```
initializer :add_routing_paths do |app|
  paths.config.routes.to_a.each do |route|
    app.routes_reloader.paths.unshift(route) if File.exists?(route)
  end
end
```

Essentially, this should take the paths to all the routes files that Rails knows about and try and add them to the routes reloader (the thing that reloades your routes file automagically for you if it is changed). You can define another initializer to be executed right after this one, you will then inspect the paths stored in the routes reloader, pull out the path that belongs to your engine, remove it from the paths array and insert it back, but at the end of the paths array. So, in your `config/application.rb`:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  initializer :munge_routing_paths, :after => :add_routing_paths do |app|
    engine_routes_path = app.routes_reloader.paths.select{|path| path =~ /<regex that matches path to my engine>/}.first
    app.routes_reloader.paths.delete(engine_routes_path)
    app.routes_reloader.paths << engine_routes_path
  end
end
```

This may or may not work, either way I don't really recommend it, it's not particularly elegant (i.e. ugly hack playing with the guts of rails).

**Use Rails 3.1**

This may not be an option, but if it is, I'd probably go with this one. In Rails 3.1 you can have 2 different types of Engines, full and mountable (here is [an SO question talking about some of the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118905/rails-3-1-engine-vs-mountable-app)). But in essence you would alter your Engine to be a mountable engine, the routes in a mountable engine are namespaced and you can explicitly include them in the routes file of your main app e.g.:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/news"
end
```

You can also scope your mounted engine routes and do all sorts of other fancy routy things (more info [here](http://piotrsarnacki.com/2010/09/14/mountable-engines/)). Long story short, if you can go to 3.1 then this is the approach to use.

**Dynamically Insert The Routes From Your Engine Into Your Main App**

One of the most well known Rails engines around at the moment is Devise. Now, devise is an engine that will potentially add quite a number of routes to your app, but if you'll look at the devise source you'll see that it doesn't actually have a `config/routes.rb` file at all! This is because devise dynamically adds its routing goodness to your main app's `routes.rb` file.

When you run the model generator that comes with devise, one of the things the generator will do is add a line such as `devise_for :model` at the top of your routes.rb file, right after the `Rails.application.routes.draw do` line. So your route.rb looks similar to this after you execute a generator to create a User model:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  ...
end
```

Now, devise_for is a magical method that comes as part of devise (in `lib/devise/rails/routes.rb`), but in essence it will create a bunch of regular routes that we all know based on the model that you generated.

The thing we need to know, is how devise insert this line in the apps `routes.rb` file, then we can write a generator in our engine that will insert any of our routes at the top of the main apps `routes.rb` file. For this we look at `lib/generators/devise/devise_generator.rb`. In the `add_devise_routes` method the last line is `route devise_route`. `Route` is a Thor action which inserts the string passed to it into the main app's `routes.rb` file. So we can write a generator of our own and do something similar e.g.:

```
class MyCrazyGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  ...
  def add_my_crazy_routes
    my_route  = "match '/news', :to => 'bar_controller#foo_action'"
    route my_route
  end
end
```

Of course you would need to make sure all the generator infrastructure is in place but that's the essence of it. Devise is written by some very smart rails dudes and used by quite a lot of people, emulating what they do is likely a pretty good way to go. Out of the 3 things that I suggested this one would be the way I would handle your issue (given that moving to rails 3.1 is probably not an option).

Comment: This is great. Thank you for your effort answering this.

Comment: I gave up on my dreams and used the devise approach rather than monkey patching the actual routing code, in the end its much more flexible especially when you are wrapping things in custom scopes.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue right now. One other not particularly elegant but safe solution I came up with is adding another engine gem at the end of your gem file, just containing the catch all route, nothing else.

**Edit**: Actually, counterintuitively, the routing gem needs to be listed **before** all other engine gems for its routes to be loaded last.

Comment: Yeah. It's basically shuffle gems around until it works strategy. It's infinitely better for gems to provide a method that you explicitly call within your routes.rb. That way you can control where you want those routes (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method in your engine that can be called to configure your engine's routes:

```
module MyEngine
    class Engine < Rails::Engine
        def self.configure_routes(mapper)
           mapper.match '/news', :to => 'news_controller#index'
        end
    end
end
```

This allows you to insert your engine's routes before a catch-all in `my_application/config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    # routes
    MyEngine::Engine.configure_routes(self)
    # more routes

    # catch-all route
end
```

Then in the engine's `my_engine/config/routes.rb` file:

```
unless Rails.application.routes.named_routes.key?(:news)
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    MyEngine::Engine.configure_routes self
  end
end
```

If you're mounting the engine and don't include the explicit route configuration method, the engine routes will be added as usual to the end of the application routes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I was playing with [sferik/rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) yesterday when I came across their routing solution. With their `rails_admin:install` rake task, they directly modify your `config/routes.rb` file by adding `mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'` at the beginning of the file so they are sure their routes always have the highest priority. That `mount` method refers to their own routes.rb :

```
RailsAdmin::Engine.routes.draw do
  # Prefix route urls with "admin" and route names with "rails_admin_"
  scope "history", :as => "history" do
    controller "history" do
      [...]
    end
  end
end
```

Could this be your solution?